# How to use Redis as a store for Express Session NestJS

Tags: node.js, express, redis, nestjs, express-session

I'm creating an API using NestJS and was trying to set up a session store for my express session but I get an error from this line. I did use express-session with Redis on a new project I created just using express beforehand to understand how Redis and express sessions worked but when I tried porting it over to NestJS it didn't work.

Main.ts

```
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import { redis } from './redis';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
```

This is the error I get

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
                               ^
TypeError: connect_redis_1.default is not a function
```

The error occurs before any other redis related feature or express-session is called. I will still include how I set up Redis & Express-Session in case that is needed.

Redis.ts

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';

export const redis = new Redis(
  port,
  'hostName',
  { password: 'password' },
);
```

Session Inside of Main.ts

```
  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redis }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24,
      },
      secret: 'mysecret',
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false,
    }),
  );
```

I did read from the NestJS documentation that i can setup Redis as a microservice however i really only need Redis for my Express-Session and dont want to set up the redis microservice if i can get this fixed.

I also use Mongoose to connect to my MongoDB which i use for my repositories inside of NestJS. Previously in other projects instead of using Redis i would setup my store in TypeORM using ORMSession if anyone has an alternative of this that works with Mongoose then that would also work.

```
const sessionRepo = getRepository(TypeORMSession);

...

store: new TypeormStore().connect(sessionRepo),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is stated here `connect_redis1.default` is not a function.

Instead, you should use `import * as connectRedis from 'connect-redis'`. [I've got an example here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/dev.to/blob/main/blog-posts/nestjs-passport-sessions/src/app.module.ts) which looks like this:

```js
import { Inject, Logger, MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as RedisStore from 'connect-redis';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import { session as passportSession, initialize as passportInitialize } from 'passport';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth';
import { REDIS, RedisModule } from './redis';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, RedisModule],
  providers: [AppService, Logger],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  constructor(@Inject(REDIS) private readonly redis: RedisClient) {}
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(
        session({
          store: new (RedisStore(session))({ client: this.redis, logErrors: true }),
          saveUninitialized: false,
          secret: 'sup3rs3cr3t',
          resave: false,
          cookie: {
            sameSite: true,
            httpOnly: false,
            maxAge: 60000,
          },
        }),
        passportInitialize(),
        passportSession(),
      )
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install @types/connect-redis

and do

import * as _connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version `^7.1.0` of `connect-redis`, you should use:

```js
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default
```

It worked for me after I debug a few hours.